# Remove or change the password from a Jetson Nano

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I received a `Jetson Nano` with a `developer kit (B01)` and a `micro SD card` from a previous research project that I want to continue, but unfortunately I didn't receive the needed password. My question is if there is a way to remove or change the password, so I am able to continue my research with the previous project setup. I am familiar with Raspberry Pis but not with the
Jetson Nano, so I would really appreciate your help.

**What I tried:**

1. Since I don't want to lose the data, I first created a `backup` of the micro SD card using `Win32 Disk Imager`, like I would on a Raspberry Pi. Based on the backup and a second micro SD card, I made successfully a copy that I can work on without the risk of losing data.
2. I tried login in with the two defaults: `user: nvidia password: nvidia` and `user: ubuntu password: ubuntu`, but it was unsuccessful. The login screen shows a custom username, so my guess is that the defaults were changed or completely deleted.
3. Since the Jetson Nano shows a `Ubuntu` login screen, my initial idea was to remove the password with this [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-lost-root-password-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). Unfortunately, this guide seems not applicable for the Jetson Nano because I didn't know that it doesn't use Grub.
4. I am currently reading about the serial debug console.